# convert shortdate to LocalDate

Tags: java, date, java-8, locale, java-time

Hi i have a short date format with me in the pattern E dd/MM , Is there any way i can convert it to LocalDate.

```
String date = "Thu 07/05";
String formatter = "E dd/MM"; 
final DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(pattern);
final LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse(date, formatter);`
```

But it throws an exception   `java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text 'Thu 07/05' could not be parsed: Unable to obtain LocalDate from TemporalAccessor: {MonthOfYear=5, DayOfMonth=7, DayOfWeek=4},ISO of type java.time.format.Parsed`

Is there any way we can fix this issue ?

Comment: Where is the Year supposed to come from?

Answer (score 3):

All you have is a month and a day - so you can create a MonthDay (to create a LocalDate you would also need a year):

```
MonthDay md = MonthDay.parse(date, formatter);
```

If you want a LocalDate, you can use the MonthDay as a starting point:

```
int year = Year.now().getValue();
LocalDate localDate = md.atYear(year);
```

Or alternatively you can use a default year in your formatter:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                                        .appendPattern(pattern)
                                        .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.YEAR, year)
                                        .toFormatter(Locale.US);

LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse(date, formatter);
```

The benefit of this method is that it will also check that the day of week (Thursday) is correct.

Comment: The OP also has the day of the week, they might want the year chosen to match that.